# RandomAccessFile: write(byte) in a loop or write(byte array), whats more effiecient?

Tags: java

I am wondring what is more efficient should I use a for loop that invokes write with each byte x times, or I should have an array that will contain my data and write it with write(byte array)?
Basically the question is write(byte array) more efficient than subsquent calls for write(byte) in a loop.
I am programing in java and using RandomAccessFile.

Comment: What do you think?  What results do you get when you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a byte array is always going to be quicker than repeated calls to write one byte at a time. There's much less overhead (method calls, IO).

Comment: yes that what I thought but I wanted to know if the write(byte array) doesn't simply call byteArray.length time to write(byte)?